# How can I get the values from a MySQL table and set into an arraylist of a class that I've created in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have two classes. One is called **Alumne** and the other one is called **Aula**. In the class alumne I have an attribute called **aulaAlumne** (it's type is Aula) which helps to connect these two classes.
These are the constructors of both classes:

Class Aula:

```java
public class Aula {
    
    int pis;
    String porta;
    int capacitat;
    String SSID;
    String passwdSSID;

    public Aula(int pis, String porta, int capacitat, String SSID, String passwdSSID) {
        this.pis = pis;
        this.porta = porta;
        this.capacitat = capacitat;
        this.SSID = SSID;
        this.passwdSSID = passwdSSID;
    }
```

Class Alumne:

```java
public class Alumne {
    
    String dni;
    String nom;
    String email;
    String telefon;
    LocalDate dataNeixement;
    Aula aulaAlumne;

    public Alumne(String dni, String nom, String email, String telefon, LocalDate dataNeixement) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefon = telefon;
        this.dataNeixement = dataNeixement;
    }

    public Alumne(String dni, String nom, String email, String telefon, LocalDate dataNeixement, Aula aulaAlumne) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefon = telefon;
        this.dataNeixement = dataNeixement;
        this.aulaAlumne = aulaAlumne;
    }
```

I need to create an array list of both of them, but when I try to create the Alumnes one, I don't know how to use the result set for the information from the alumne table in MySQL.
I have two foreign keys in the **table** **alumnes** from the other **table aules** called **aules_pis**, **aules_porta**:

Table alumnes:
[image]

Table aules:

[image]

So I'm trying to get the **alumnes** information with this method, but I don't know how I can get the result set from the last two columns (foreign keys), because I need to put an Aula object in the constructor to create the Alumne object and finally create the arraylist of Alumne.

```java
public ArrayList<Alumne> getAlumnes() throws AplicacioException {
    ArrayList<Alumne> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Statement sentencia;
        sentencia = conn.getConnection().createStatement();
        sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM alumnes");
    ResultSet rs = sentencia.getResultSet();
    while (rs.next()) {
        ret.add(new Alumne(rs.getString("dniEstudiant"), rs.getString("nom"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("telefon"), rs.getDate("dataNeixement").toLocalDate()));
    }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new AplicacioException("Ha ocurrido un error al cargar los datos del alumno");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your SQL query to join the two tables

```
SELECT al.*, au.*
FROM alumnes al
INNER JOIN aula au
ON al.aules_pis = au.pis
AND al.aules_porta = au.porta;
```

and then in the while loop

```
ret.add(new Alumne(rs.getString("dniEstudiant"), rs.getString("nom"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("telefon"), rs.getDate("dataNeixement").toLocalDate(), new Aula(rs.getString("pis"), rs.getString("porta"), rs.getString("capacitat"), rs.getString("ssidwifi"), , rs.getString("dauwifi"))));
```